# avoid multiple clicks on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It's probably sthg simple, but I still didn't find a solution, I would like to avoid multiple clicks on a button, before finishing an ajax call.

Here is what I tried :

```
<button id="btn_pay"></button>

$("#btn_pay").click( function() {
    $('#btn_pay').prop('disabled', true);
    Stripe.card.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);
});

           var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                   alert("success");
                },complete:function(){
                    //we re-enable the button
                    $('#btn_pay').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
```

Problem :
If I click several times on the button, many alerts appear, it's like the button is still active, and many ajax call are done instead of jsut 1 at a time..

Any idea ?

Comment: Use some Boolean flag, and update it on click and ajax complete

Comment: your code logic should work as expected

Comment: Is `#btn_pay` an input or button element?

Comment: @kmsdev OP has posted relevant HTML markup

Comment: @kmsdev the element is on the first line of the snippet.

Comment: Just `disable` the button after click and `enable` after `ajax` success.

Comment: @Chayan this is what is doing OP (even better using complete handler). Issue comes from somewhere else, maybe he is binding multiple click handlers

Comment: Which is what OP already did.

Comment: It should work http://jsfiddle.net/h47814ek/

Comment: use .bind() and .unbind()

Comment: Is there a URL for the Ajax call in your code or did you just omit it for this post?  If there is no URL, it's probably completing before alerting.

Comment: @raveenanigam Why that? Please explain

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `stripeResponseHandler` is being called after `$('#btn_pay').prop('disabled', true);`, and at the end of that function is a `complete:function()` where you re-enable the button upon completion of the AJAX calling. Isn't that what's happening? You complete AJAX, `complete` is called and re-enable the button, the code is closing its cycle.

Comment: @user2182349 yes there is an url in the ajax call, I omited it to keep evthg simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control it with a simple variable:

```
    <button id="btn_pay"></button>

    var disabled = false; // global var to control button state

    $("#btn_pay").click( function() {
        if (disabled) {
            return; 
        }

        Stripe.card.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);
        disabled = true; // button is now blocked
    });

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
          $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(data){
                       disabled = false; // release button lock
                       alert("success");
                    },complete:function(){
                       disabled = false; // release button lock
                    },fail: function(){
                       disabled = false; // when fail, you need to release the lock too
                    }
            });
      }
```

Other solutions with event handlers may work for you too, but this is a simpler way to implement this feature.

Comment: My favorite solution, because you don't touch UI at all, even the button, just a clean javascript. Even if you have multiple buttons or other type of triggers that want to run that ajax code, you'll always know that there will only be one request.

Comment: @Julien, if you want the ajax request to work only one time and then not to work at all, then remove the lines from the code above with `disabled = false;`

Comment: @Hovo, what do you mean? "the lines above disabled=false" ?

Comment: @Julien What Hovo wants to say is that if you want to allow one single click when the user hits the button, you just have to remove the disabled = false from the ajax handlers. When the ajax ends, the user won't be able to click the button anymore. But if what you want is just to avoid double cick on a button, then this solution fits well for you. :)

Comment: The code above contains code `disabled=false;` on the lines 18, 21 and 23. The code on those lines remove the lock on ajax so user can later click on the button again and repeat the ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

**Try** `e.preventdefault();`

> The event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an
>   element from happening. For example: Prevent a submit button from
>   submitting a form. Prevent a link from following the URL.

*I have Also facine this type of problem , i have prevent it by using this  .. May be it will help you*

```
<button id="btn_pay"></button>

$("#btn_pay").click( function(e) {
     e.preventdefault();
    $('#btn_pay').prop('disabled', true);
    Stripe.card.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);
});

           var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                   alert("success");
                },complete:function(){
                    //we re-enable the button
                    $('#btn_pay').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why should OP *try it*? You need to provide explanation for future users who come to see the question, understand why this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code:

`.unbind()` Remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.

`.bind` Attach a handler to an event for the elements.

```
<button id="btn_pay"></button>

<script>
$("#btn_pay").click( function(e) {
    $("#btn_pay").unbind("click");
    $('#btn_pay').prop('disabled', true);
    Stripe.card.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);
});

           var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                   alert("success");
                },complete:function(){
                    //we re-enable the button
                    $("#btn_pay").bind("click");
                }
            });
</script>
```

Checkout the tutorials :
http://api.jquery.com/bind/

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid multiple clicks on button by adding loading image untill your ajax call is completed in beforeSend: event.
for example:

```
$.ajax
        ({ 
            url: 'your-url',
            data: "",
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function() {
                      $("#loading-image").show();
                   },
            success: function(result)
            {
                //alert(result);
                $("#loading-image").hide();
            }
       });
```

You have to keep image in div id 'loading-image' and by default display:none(CSS Setup).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="loader_div_all" style="position: absolute ! important;opacity: 0.60;display: none;">
<img src="ajaxSpinner.gif" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 1060px;'">
```

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
            url: 'PATH_TO_AJAX_REQUEST_URL',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {/*Data set here*/},
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#loader_div_all").css('display','block');
            },
            success: function(resp) {
              $("#loader_div_all").css('display','none');
              /*Perform Ajax Success Action Here*/
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Link the disabled state of the button to the response function firing. This way the visual cue and the button behaviour should match.

```
$("#btn_pay").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).prop('disabled')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    Stripe.card.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);
});
```

(It would be better to pass a callback re-enabling the button to `stripeResponseHandler`, so that that function is not tied to a specific button calling it).